# Angular 2 - Send value between services

Tags: service, angular, observable

I'm trying to make the `canActivate` function returns `true` or `false`.

The boolean value will come from the function `signin()` in file `login.service.ts`
in `response.json().message` and appear `true` or `false` but does not appear the value when I use `this.loginService.logado()` in `canActivate` function in file `auth.guard.ts`.

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

**login.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Config} from '../config';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService{
    token: string;
    userId: string;
    constructor (private _http: Http) {}

    login(contentLogin){
        const body = JSON.stringify(contentLogin);
        const header = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        return this._http.post(Config.URL_SITE + 'auth/login', body, {headers: header})
            .map(response => response.json())
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }

    signin() {
        this.token = localStorage['token'];
        this.userId = localStorage['userId'];

        const body = JSON.stringify({token: this.token, userId: this.userId});
        const header = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        return this._http.post(Config.URL_SITE + 'auth/signin', body, {headers: header})
            .map(response => response.json().message) //true or false
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }
}
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {LoginService} from './login/login.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        return this.loginService.signin()
    }
}
```

Comment: Use return keyword   `. map((response) =>{ return response. Json(). message}`)...

Comment: Hi Micronyks, in the `canActivate` keeps showing the Observable object, instead of only the value boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit a weird behavior of `canActivate` but it does wait for the observable to complete, instead of just for an event of the observable.

You can workaround using

```
return this.loginService.signin().first();
```

Don't forget to import the `take` operator.

Comment: Hi Gunter, I add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';` but using `console.log(this.loginService.logado().take(1))` to see the value of the function continues printing the Observable object

Comment: I assume `logado` is the `signin` method in the code of your question. It is expected that it prints `Observable`. Not sure what you expect. If you want the value. you need to subscribe, then you get passed the value to the callback you pass to `subscribe(...)`. This is what the router does with the observable that is returned by `canActivate` - it subscribes to it. (BTW If you subscribe yourself, you get a `Subscription` which can't be used by the router). You can use `map(...)` to be able to access the value when the router subscribes and and event is emitted.

Comment: I expect in the `auth.guard.ts` file in `canActivate` function returns true or false. This value I get through `signin()` function in `login.service.ts` file. The following implementation `this.loginService.logado().subscribe(data => { return data }, error => { return error.message })` appears `true` in Data and `false` in Error, however, this appeared the following error: canActivate the function can not be `void` but `boolean`

Comment: You can't get `true´ or `false` returned from an observable. `CanActivate` is working just fine with an `Observable` that emits `true` and `false` values. The only problem is that it doesn't continue when it receives the first value but waits for the observable to close. This is what `take(1)` takes care of. Therefore the code in my answer should do what you want.

Comment: Insert the end of the function canActivate `return this.loginService.signin().take(1);` and it worked. The pages are protected. Just this appearing the following error on the console: `Error: Uncaught (in promise): false`

Comment: I don't know what exactly is going on in your app and there is an open issue that the router should handle errors from guards better but I guess this should fix it for you as well: Change `error => Observable.throw(error.json())` to `error => Observable.of(false)` to not forward the exception but treat it as `false` value.